# how to insert the See All link in a drupal view block

Tags: views, blocks

i created a  News block that display only 3 lasted news, and i want create a button "See All News" 
how i can do it ?

Comment: thanks an how i do the link "read more" for every news in block ?

Comment: i have 6 news , i created a view block called "News block view" , this bloock display 3 lasted news , i would create a link in the footer of the block called "See all news" this link redirect me in the view page of all news , i want create a link "read more" in every news in the block , you understand?

Comment: yes read more for every news in block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the footer section of the view add a global text area with the link of the See all news.

**STEP 1:**

[image]

**STEP 2:**

[image]

**STEP 3:**

[image]

Once you are done adding a field in the footer, save the view and the See all news link would work as expected.

**For creating the Read more link**

1. Go to the body field of the news.
2. In the Rewrite Result, you have a checkbox "Trim this field to a maximum length".
3. Once you check the checkbox, you have the option to "Add a read-more link if output is trimmed.".
4. Add the Read more text and use the [path] token for getting the path of the node.
5. Save the view and the Read more link would be there for all the news that you have.

Adding an image to help you in a better way:
[image]

Comment: thank you bro , but i want also create a "Read more" link for every news

Comment: I have updated my answer.